# Why does my app start successfully with 'flutter run' and 'flutter run --profile,' but it immediately closes when using 'flutter run --release'?

Tags: android, flutter

Why does my app work well in debug and profile modes when I create a custom Flutter SDK and include it in the pubspec.yaml file like this

mysdk:
path: ../my_sdk

But when I switch to release mode, the app starts and then immediately closes? What could be the reason for this behavior?

I added mysdk: ^x.y.z to the pubspec.yaml file as instructed, but it's still not working. Do I need to register it separately on pub.dev?

this is my error log

- Throwing new exception 'no non-static method "Ld4/a;.commandListener(J[BI)V"' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ld4/a;.stateListener(JI)V"
- native: #02 pc 00339224  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Unsafe_park +160) (BuildId: 5252e4c81acd91f2620b389dd7543d90)
- at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1103)

Comment: What's the error? Can you share the logcat?

Comment: I just added logchat